# What happens when you use WinJS.Promise.Timeout(undefined)?

Tags: javascript, windows, winjs

I am trying to write a Windows app. I am curious to know what happens when you pass WinJS.Promise.Timeout() undefined value rather than a numerical milliseconds value. Will it be equivalent to passing the function a value of 0, or the behavior is unpredictable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [code](https://github.com/winjs/winjs/blob/master/src/js/WinJS/Promise.js) the setImmidiate function is called when this value is not specified. This means the promise is fulfilled when the current task is completed.

When you pass 0 a JavaScript setTimeout function is used internally. This function is limited to 250 calls per second on some systems. When passing 'undefined' to WinJS.Promise.Timeout() it doesn't use a setTimeOut call. So it could be a bit faster in some cases.

You can find more info on the setImmidate function on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453394.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As Sorskoot explains, the code makes it clear that setImmediate is called if the interval is zero or undefined. The docs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br229729.aspx) state this clearly:

```
timeout 
Type: Number

The timeout period in milliseconds. If this value is zero or not specified, msSetImmediate is called, otherwise setTimeout is called.
```

It's really just saying that a zero or undefined timeout should just yield the UI thread and then complete.